# list the singer details who had not performed in any movie

Tags: sql, oracle

Performance

```
PerformanceId   SingerId    MovieId NumberofSongs  
  1              1            1        2
  2              3            1        4
  3              2            2        6
  4              4            5        3
  5              5            5        3 
  6              2            6        2
  7              4            6        5
  8              6            4        6
  9              6            3        3
  10             4            3        4
```

Singer

```
SingerId    SingerName  City        DOB        Gender
   1           A       Hyderabad    14-Apr-65   M
   2           B       Chennai      25-May-84   M
   3           C       Bangalore    14-Sep-78   F
   4           D       Hyderabad    17-Jan-70   M
   5           E       Hyderabad    18-Mar-87   F
   6           F       Bangalore    23-Aug-75   F
   7           g       hyderabad    17-Jan-70   M
```

Movie

```
 MovieId    MovieName   ReleaseDate
  1         AAA          12-Jan-15
  2         BBB          19-Sep-12
  3         CCC          23-Jul-10
  4         DDD          06-Oct-01
  5         EEE          08-Nov-05
  6         FFF          18-Apr-99
  7         GGG          07-Aug-12
```

I have an issue please clarify me question.
List the Singer details who has not performed in any movies.

I tried this query its not working my query is

```
select count(a.singer_id) as count_movie,
       a.singer_name,
       a.city,
       a.dob,
       a.gender 
  from singer a 
   inner join performance b on 
              a.singer_id=b.singer_id group by    
              a.singer_name,a.city,a.dob,a.gender
       having count(a.singer_id)=0;
```

Help me out

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, I think you can achieve this with just a left outer join, like so:

```
with performance as (select 1 performanceid, 1 singerid, 1 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 2 performanceid, 3 singerid, 1 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 3 performanceid, 2 singerid, 2 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 4 performanceid, 4 singerid, 5 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 5 performanceid, 5 singerid, 5 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 6 performanceid, 2 singerid, 6 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 7 performanceid, 4 singerid, 6 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 8 performanceid, 6 singerid, 4 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 9 performanceid, 6 singerid, 3 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 10 performanceid, 4 singerid, 3 movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual union all
                     select 11 performanceid, 8 singerid, null movieid, 2 numberofsongs from dual),
          singer as (select 1 singerid, 'A' singername, 'Hyderabad' city, to_date('14/04/1965', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'M' gender from dual union all
                     select 2 singerid, 'B' singername, 'Chennai' city, to_date('25/05/1984', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'M' gender from dual union all
                     select 3 singerid, 'C' singername, 'Bangalore' city, to_date('14/09/1978', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'F' gender from dual union all
                     select 4 singerid, 'D' singername, 'Hyderabad' city, to_date('17/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'M' gender from dual union all
                     select 5 singerid, 'E' singername, 'Hyderabad' city, to_date('18/03/1987', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'F' gender from dual union all
                     select 6 singerid, 'F' singername, 'Bangalore' city, to_date('23/08/1975', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'F' gender from dual union all
                     select 7 singerid, 'g' singername, 'Hyderabad' city, to_date('17/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'M' gender from dual union all
                     select 8 singerid, 'H' singername, 'Chennai' city, to_date('23/02/1975', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dbo, 'M' gender from dual),
           movie as (select 1 movieid, 'AAA' moviename, to_date('12/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 2 movieid, 'BBB' moviename, to_date('19/09/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 3 movieid, 'CCC' moviename, to_date('23/07/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 4 movieid, 'DDD' moviename, to_date('06/10/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 5 movieid, 'EEE' moviename, to_date('08/11/2005', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 6 movieid, 'FFF' moviename, to_date('18/04/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual union all
                     select 7 movieid, 'GGG' moviename, to_date('07/08/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') releasedate from dual)
select s.*
from   singer s
       left join performance p on (s.singerid = p.singerid)
where  p.movieid is null;

  SINGERID SINGERNAME CITY      DBO        GENDER
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------
         8 H          Chennai   23/02/1975 M     
         7 g          Hyderabad 17/01/1970 M
```

This works whether or not the movieid in the performance table is null or not (assuming that a null value means a singer sang somewhere that wasn't a movie).

Comment: if the movieid in NULL then that would be a non-movie performance, the question is those singers who have not performed in a movie, so it does matter if that column is null or not null I believe. Also not sure why you have 8 singers but question has 7

Comment: That's because I added an example of a singer who had performed but not in a movie to show that my query caters for both scenarios.

Comment: but singer 8 has not sung in a movie, therefore should not be in the result. (Q = singers not in movies)

Comment: ignore me, doh! sorry. what was I thinking

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of songs less than 1 :

```
SELECT        Performance.PerformanceId, Performance.singer_id, Performance.movie_id, Performance.nof_songs, Singer.singer_id AS Expr1, Singer.singer_name, Singer.City, 
                         Singer.DOB, Singer.Gender, movies.movie_id AS Expr2, movies.movie_name, movies.release_date
FROM            Performance INNER JOIN
                         Singer ON Performance.singer_id = Singer.singer_id INNER JOIN
                         movies ON Performance.movie_id = movies.movie_id
WHERE        (Performance.nof_songs < 1)
```

To get only singer details :

```
SELECT        Singer.singer_id AS Expr1, Singer.singer_name, Singer.City, Singer.DOB, Singer.Gender
FROM            Performance INNER JOIN
                         Singer ON Performance.singer_id = Singer.singer_id INNER JOIN
                         movies ON Performance.movie_id = movies.movie_id
WHERE        (Performance.nof_songs < 1)
```

Comment: hear i need to get only singer details who has not performed in any of the movie

Comment: thank you buddy i tried it in another way its also working                         select * from singer where singer_id not in (select distinct singer_id from performance)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select * 
    from singer,
         performance,
         movie
   where singer.singerId=performance.singer_id
     and performance.movie_id <> movie.movie_id(+);
```

or

```
  select * 
    from singer,
         performance
   where singer.singerId=performance.singer_id
     and performance.movie_id NOT IN (select movie_id from movie);
```

It may help you

Answer (score 0):

If a singer not in performance table it has not performed in any of movie:

```
SELECT * FROM Singer
WHERE SingerId NOT IN (SELECT SingerId FROM Performance)
```